# How to create a Hyperlink within the current Notebook?

Tags: programming

Using “Create Hyperlink” dialog window I can create a link to a tagged cell in my notebook (it's “Destination notebook: Current notebook” radio button).

Now, I can't figure it out how to create such links with `Hyperlink[]` command.

I tried

```
Hyperlink["label", {"", "tag"}]
Hyperlink["label", {None, "tag"}]
Hyperlink["label", {Automatic, "tag"}]
```

etc., but nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `EvaluationNotebook[]` to point to the actual notebook you are working in (you don't even have to save it). First, create a cell with a tag:

```
CellPrint@Cell["Target cell", "Text", CellTags -> {"target"}]
```

and then create the link that points to the target cell:

```
Hyperlink["link", {EvaluationNotebook[], "target"}]
```

Clicking the link will select the cell with tag `"target"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry for such a late thanks.

Comment: Just one remark. With `{EvaluationNotebook[], ...}` I get a `{NotebookObject[FrontEndObject[LinkObject[...]], 12], target}` in the status line when hovering over the "link", while it’s just "target" with the “Create Hyperlink” dialog.

Comment: @Alekh I guess you have to live with that, as I don't think there is any way to format the status notification of `Hyperlink`. Unfortunately, a `StatusArea` wrapper does not overwrite it. Perhaps it is possible to create a customizable hyperlink using lower level interface elements.

Comment: An extension: As noted in [How to create permanent intra-notebook links](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88755/how-to-create-permanent-intra-notebook-links), `EvaluationNotebook[]` may be replaced by another destination notebook (which I would have thought was obvious, but, hey, a new system can really undermine one's confidence until you get a good feel for how it works).