# How to create permanent intra-notebook links

Tags: formatting, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a documentation notebook for a package and have entries which reference other entries. I'd like to include the hyperlinks in text formatted cells so that when a reader clicks on that link, they go directly to the cell with the corresponding label.

I have the appropriate destination cells labeled, but having no luck creating text hyperlinks which are permanent. The hyperlink tool (Ctrl+Shift+H) creates links which give an error specifying that the document cannot be found when clicked, even if the file has not been moved. I also attempted the solution found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-within-the-current-notebook), but the `NotebookObject` created by `EvaluationNotebook[]` does not survive opening a new instance of the notebook.

How can I create these links which will work each time the document is open, regardless of file location? Thanks.

Edit: Quite obviously not a duplicate. The directed question neither brings up this specific issue of hyperlinks as a concern, nor does the answer provided to it solve the issue. The exact question that this is marked a duplicate of is even linked to within the body of this question as one which does not satisfy the issue presented here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution at [How to create a Hyperlink within the current Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-within-the-current-notebook) can work with `EvaluationNotebook[]` replaced by the actual file name.