# Why the graphics are not saved in notebook?

Tags: export, graphics3d

I'm new to Mathematica, and use it for visualize some distributions now.

One of my 3D distribution functions has several hundreds coefficients and the `ListDensityPlot3D` function takes about one hour to generate the plot. After I saved the file and exited the kernel, it seems all the pictures are lost, with `Out[37]:` left empty.

To test what happened, I tried some `ListDensityPlot3D` examples from the official website, saved and exited the kernel. This time the pictures are saved, although I cannot use `%10` to retrieve them. But to view them is enough for my purpose.

I also tried `Export["plot.3ds",plotObject,"3DS"]`, but the export failed with the error: `Export::nodta: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the 3DS format.`

So, the situation is that I can neither export the picture nor save the graphs in notebook. I don't want to spend an hour everytime to replot the graph. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the Save function ? You can use Get later to load the saved object.

Comment: Is this what you want: [Referencing cells after reopening a saved notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95892/5478)?