# How to hyperlink a plot output?

Tags: boxes, hyperlink, cells

I would like to adapt the following instructions [How to create a Hyperlink within the current Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-within-the-current-notebook) to have a hyperlink to an output of a simple plot such as

```
Plot[x,{x,0,1}]
```

How to deal with the fact that the target is not a text but a graphics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following syntax works:

```
CellPrint[Cell[
   BoxData[ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}]]],
   "Output", 
   CellTags -> {"target"}]
]]
```

It is documented under Cell -> Scope.

```
Hyperlink["link", {EvaluationNotebook[], "target"}]
(* Out: hyperlink pointing to the plot *)
```

MichaelE2 points out in a comment that `ExpressionCell` can be used:

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}], "Output", CellTags -> "tag"
]
```

Note that you can also add tags manually through the drop down menu that you get by right-clicking on cells:

[image: How to add tags]

Comment: I have noticed that when I close my notebook I lose all the Cell Tags added manually from the drop down menu. Is there any way to leave them permanent?

Comment: @AndreaG did you save the notebook after adding cell tags? Works fine on Win7 V11.1.1

Comment: @Kuba I was pretty sure to have done it. However, I just redid it and it worked. I may have done some mistake. If I notice something weird next time I open the notebook I will let you know

Comment: One can use `ExpressionCell` and skip the box stuff: `CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}], "Output", CellTags -> "tag"]`